# How to fetch stock details and key statistics from yahoo finance using php

Tags: php, xml, json, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

As the question suggest can you please tell me how i can fetch details regarding stocks (current price,Market Cap,open price, bid price etc) and key statistical information such as Trailing P/E, Forward P/E,Profit Margin (ttm),Revenue Per Share (ttm),Book Value Per Share (mrq) etc. Can you also give a simple example/script (parsing Json/xml) for fetching these details. I want to fetch the details of [this stock](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SUZLON.BO&ql=0). Most of the tutorial for yahoo finance api in web is for C# and also vague regarding details. Ca

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following posts and code sample on how to fetch stock prices from Yahoo! using PHP and json. This is by no means a complete solution just a baseline on how to go about it.
It is **important** that you at least try something and post you code because it makes it easier for the community to catch-on what you attempting.

[PHP: How to get stock quote data from Yahoo! Finance? (Complete Code and Tutorial)](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/php-how-to-get-stock-quote-data-from-yahoo-finance-complete-code-and-tutorial/)

Now you have to take the result dataset from the PHP and encode it into json format which you can use on your front-end. For this part you might want to look at this link instead:

[JSON Example to html table](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp)

There might be examples that explain or even provide a full solution to your problem but I that would require more research on your part. This is just to get you going!

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the key statistics from BarChart.com, here is a simple function script:

```
library(XML)
getKeyStats <- function(symbol) {
  barchart.URL <- "http://www.barchart.com/profile.php?sym="
  barchart.URL.Suffix <- "&view=key_statistics"
  html_table <- readHTMLTable(paste(barchart.URL, symbol, barchart.URL.Suffix, sep = ""))
  df_keystats = html_table[[5]]
  print(df_keystats)
 }
```